# Next, If, and copying only data which matches an input

Tags: vba, for-loop, if-statement

It's been a decade since I've written VBA and trying to reach out to see what I broke. I wrote a macro which copies data from one sheet to another, 1 column at a time for 4 different columns, and pastes it in the next free cell. This formula worked but I would like to adjust it to only copy certain data. Below is an example, I am trying to only copy A if the date value in E is equal to the input date value you enter when the macro starts. I am having most trouble balancing the `If/Then` with the `For/Next`. Every time I place an `End If` or `Next`, I receive errors.

```
Dim DateValue As Variant
DateValue = InputBox("Enter the date to copy")

'copy and paste column A to column A if E = input date
For Each Cell In Worksheets("Enrichment Report").Range("E:E")
    If Cell.Value = DateValue Then
        Sheets("Enrichment Report").Select
        iMaxRow = 100
        For iCol = 1 To 1
            For iRow = 2 To iMaxRow
                With Worksheets ("Enrichment Report").Cells(iRow, iCol)
                    If .Value = "" Then
                        'empty row, do nothing
                    Else
                        .Copy
                        Sheets("Intake Form").Select
                        Range (A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
                        Activesheet.Paste
                    End If
                End With
            Next
        End If
    Next iRow
Next iCol
```

Comment: I indented your code with [this](http://rubberduckvba.com/indentation) rubberduck tool. Now we can actually see what's going on!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could  use `AutoFilter()` and avoid looping

also, use `Application.InputBox()` method instead of VBA `InputBox()` function to exploit its `Type` parameter and force a numeric input

```
Sub mmw()
    Dim targetSht As Worksheet
    Set targetSht = Sheets("Intake Form")

    Dim DateValue As Variant
    DateValue = Application.InputBox("Enter the date to copy", , , , , , , 2)


    With Worksheets("Enrichment Report") ' reference your "source" sheet
        With .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp)) ' reference its columns A:E cells from row 1 down to column E last not empty cell
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>" 'filter on referenced range 1st column with not empty cells
            .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=CStr(CDate(DateValue))

            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then _
                .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                Sheets("Intake Form").Cells(Sheets("Intake Form").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)  '<--| if any cell filtered other than headers (which get always filtered) then copy filtered values to "paste" sheet

        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked great, than you! Was able to apply this style to all the columns successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following code will be much easier for you to follow

Also, it will be much faster looping through occupied cells with data in Column E, and not the entire column.

***Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

Dim LastRow As Long, iMaxRow As Long, iCol As Long, iRow As Long
Dim DateValue As Variant
Dim Cell As Range

DateValue = InputBox("Enter the date to copy")

With Worksheets("Enrichment Report")
    ' get last row with data in column E
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

    'copy and paste column A to column A if E = input date
    For Each Cell In .Range("E1:E" & LastRow)
        If Cell.Value = DateValue Then
            iMaxRow = 100
            For iCol = 1 To 1
                For iRow = 2 To iMaxRow
                    If .Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = "" Then
                        'empty row, do nothing
                    Else
                        .Cells(iRow, iCol).Copy
                        Sheets("Intake Form").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll                       
                    End If

                Next iRow
            Next iCol
        End If
    Next Cell
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I did receive an error (run time) 438 stating "object doesn't support this property or method" on the line: Sheets("Intake Form").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Paste

Comment: CORRECTION: Thank you for the response, I did receive an error (run time) 438 and fixing Offset(1).Paste to just a selection and then activesheet.paste on the next row solved that issue. However, the formula is not copying the corresponding value from column A. For example E1 does not equal the date entered but A1 is being pasted when the formula hits on E2 being equal to the date entered instead of pasting A2.

Comment: The new paste option removes any error messages, but the code just copies all of A into A on the other sheet and isn't pulling based on the date in E.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, with the proper indentation done by CallumDA, it should be written as below. Also there is a typo in the `Range (A"`, it should be `Range ("A"`:

```
For Each Cell In Worksheets("Enrichment Report").Range("E:E")
    If Cell.Value = DateValue Then
        Sheets("Enrichment Report").Select
        iMaxRow = 100
        For iCol = 1 To 1
            For iRow = 2 To iMaxRow
                With Worksheets ("Enrichment Report").Cells(iRow, iCol)
                    If .Value = "" Then
                        'empty row, do nothing
                    Else
                        .Copy
                        Sheets("Intake Form").Select
                        Range ("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
                        Activesheet.Paste
                    End If
                End With
            Next iRow
        Next iCol
    End If
Next
```